# What is the purpose of using (.code) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a code in Javascript which runs an If statement with a reference .code. I've searched all over to find why and I did not find a useful answer. Here is an example:

```
function X(Y) {
    if ((ord.status == JSON.stringify( (JSON.parse(ord.status).code == ordStatus.Del.code)){ 
        //code here 
    }
}
```

Comment: By "extension", do you mean something like "file extension", like the ".exe" or the ".html" at the end of a filename?

Comment: I suggest reading a bit of documentation about objects in javascript

Comment: I'm noticing an issue: your parentheses don't match. There should be two right parentheses to match the ones on the left.

Answer (score 4):

`.code` is not an "extension" here. It is a reference to the `code` property of a Javascript object.

Here, `ord.status` is a string that can be parsed as a Javascript object that contains a `code` property.

`JSON.parse(ord.status)` parses the `ord.status` string into a Javascript object.  Then, `.code` references the `code` property in that object.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, your parentheses don't match, which means that this piece of JavaScript is invalid as it stands. I'll take a good faith analysis, however, and assume that the missing parentheses will go on the end of the `if` expression before the body.

Since your question appears to be about the `if` statement having this `.code` applied to it, let's just parse the expression to see what's going on using Mozilla's documentation on [operator precendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for reference. We'll use the hypothetical method `m` to replace `// code here`, then use `I` to represent an identifier, `E` to represent an expression, and `S` to represent a statement:

```
if ((ord.status == JSON.stringify( (JSON.parse(ord.status).code == ordStatus.Del.code)))){ m(); }

IF (( I .  I    ==  I  .   I     ( ( I  .  I  ( I . I    ). I   ==     I    . I . I  )))){ E(); } // lexing
IF ((I.I == I.I((I.I(I.I).I == I.I.I)))){ E(); } // remove spaces
IF ((E.I == E.I((E.I(E.I).I == E.I.I)))){ E(); } // get names from scope
IF ((E.I == E.I((E.I(E).I == E.I.I)))){ E(); } // member access
IF ((E.I == E.I((E(E).I == E.I.I)))){ E(); } // member access
IF ((E.I == E.I((E.I == E.I.I)))){ E(); } // function invoke
IF ((E.I == E.I((E == E.I.I)))){ E(); } // member access
IF ((E.I == E.I((E == E.I)))){ E(); } // member access
IF ((E.I == E.I((E == E)))){ E(); } // member access
IF ((E == E.I((E == E)))){ E(); } // member access
IF ((E == E((E == E)))){ E(); } // member access
IF ((E == E((E)))){ E(); } // equality check
IF ((E == E(E))){ E(); } // parentheses
IF ((E == E)){ E(); } // function invoke
IF ((E)){ E(); } // equality test
IF (E){ E(); } // parentheses
IF (E){ E; } // function invoke
IF (E){ S } // expression eval statement
IF (E) S // block statement
S // if statement
```

As you can see here, each member access operation (the `.`) is correctly being applied to an expression on the left and an identifier on the right each time it is used. It is not being applied to the `if` statement, and the `if` statement is correctly being parsed as the whole statement. Even though I did add extra parentheses to make your answer make sense, the result is still the same, as such a possibility would only come up if there were too *many* parentheses on the right.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the answer to the right question?

Comment: @Dummy The OP does appear to know what an member access operation is, based on a comment to a (now deleted) previous answer of mine. My next best interpretation of the question is that he's seeing something weird about how it's being used.